# GStreamer: send synchronized h.264 + raw data over RTP

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I have a camera that produces HD images as well as sideband metadata for each image. The size of the metadata is fixed, although undecided as yet. The max size of the metadata is 200KB per image, although I expect we will end-up transfering only 50KB per image.

Currently the images are h.264 encoded and streamed over RTP using the GStreamer RTSP server.

I have experimented with rtpvrawpay / rtpvrawdepay and managed to transfer / receive metadata that way.

I am looking for suggestions / pointers so that the metadata can be resynchronized with each frame on the receiver.

If I set the same DTS/PTS on the raw image and metadata buffers on the sender (server) would I be able to use those timestamps on the receiver side to resynchronize the two?